# Combining OpenCV, Python, Tkinter and PiCamera

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I'm having problems with using OpenCV, Python, Tkinter and PiCamera in a program.

- A Tkinter window is used to display and set the values to be used in OpenCV:

  [image: TkinterWindow]
- I am trying to continuously read and process the video feed from PiCamera currently I am using:

  ```
  while True:
      for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
          root.update_idletasks()
  ```

But after some reading on internet I found that using `update()` is not advisable, so I tried my luck to understand threading but I failed. There are a lot of examples with `VideoCapture()` which is used with USB cameras but not a lot with PiCamera. Is there any other way than threading?

Comment: *"Is there any other way than threading?"*: As long as you need a `loop` to do `.capture(...` you have to use a thread. Try this approach [Task in a thread to avoid freezing the `Tk().mainloop()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54405046/7414759), replace `enviar` with your function to do `while ... .capture(..` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `root.after(...)`.  Below is a sample code:

```
# define a variable used to stop the image capture
do_image_capture = True

def capture_image():
    if do_image_capture:
        camera.capture(rawCapture, format='bgr', use_video_port=True)
        # do whatever you want on the captured data
        ...
        root.after(100, capture_image) # adjust the first argument to suit your case

capture_image()
```

Below sample code is using thread:

```
import threading

stop_image_capture = False

def capture_image():
    for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format='bgr', use_video_port=True)
        # do whatever you want on the capture image
        ....
        if stop_image_capture:
            break

t = threading.Thread(target=capture_image)
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
```